# Android navigation app force closed

Tags: android, navigation

Hi I am working with android.I am trying to add my personalised login page before the navigation drawer page starts.But it looks force closed. I just changed oncreate set content view to my page. Then by clicking on a button on page, its set content view to normal as before, it force closed.I cant find the error. please help me , I am new to android

here is my code

```
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    ImageButton img1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    //ImageButton img2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

              img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start new activity with calling Intent like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

For more details see [**this tutotial**](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/)

Comment: what is LoginActivity.this  here u used??

Comment: I used Fragment so any problem with??

Comment: If you want only simple navigation application then avoid use Fragment use Activity instead...

Comment: I used     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);     here MainActivity is my oncreate java and Login is my login page..

Comment: See my answer carefully please see tutorial provide link by me that given you complete explanation....